# Core Plot: How do I set the x-axis go through zero and at the bottom and y-axis to zero and left?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am a newbie to CorePlot and finally managed to get some scattered line plot display.
How can I set the X-Axis to zero and on the bottom and the Y-Axis to zero and on the left of the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the xRange of your plotSpace to

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
```

and the yRange to

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];
```

where xMax and yMax are the maximum values for your X and Y axis, respectively.

By the default, each axis will be located at the coordinate corresponding to the low end of your plot range - 0.0 if you set your ranges as above.  It sounds like this is where you want them, but you can alter the location of the axis if you want to by setting `xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` or `yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` to something other than 0.0, like this:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(4.0);  // or whatever
axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.0); // or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift2:

First, appropriate steps to get to the next statements, then:

```
let axisSet = graph.axisSet as CPTXYAxisSet
let x = axisSet.xAxis
x.orthogonalPosition = yMin
```

Further steps to configure x

The same format can be used to get the y crossover if you want it at some other point on your x axis than the first data point you have.  Note that if you use dates for your x axis, you will need to use NSDateFormatter based statements to compare the date values.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to include that information. I did it for you here but keep it in mind :).